# Showing large image at original size on mobile devices

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

I have a very high resolution 'cartoon' road map with a number of locations also drawn on. Users can click on locations drawn on the map to navigate to related pages.

The map is not drawn to scale at all hence I decided to map co-ordinates on the image to create the required links rather than as a GMaps overlay or similar. This works assuming the user has a desktop which shows the image to the full width of a PC monitor, but I'm struggling with how to serve such a high resolution (approx 4000px x 3000px) image in a way which is intuitive for mobile users to navigate and still be able to see sufficient detail (ie. showing the map at original size but with perhaps pinch/drag functionality similar to an actual GMap). Any suggestions?

Comment: You can make a wrapper with ```overflow: scroll``` and place there your image at original size, so mobile users can scrolling it like a map.

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance thanks, tried this out and certainly an improvement. I've just come across a zoom/pan module called Magnifik which fulfils the same purpose but makes it easier to embed a thumbnail on the page which expands on click.